# How to add UniqueField constraint on integer field?

Tags: 8, entities

The title basically says it all. I have the following field definition in an Entity class:

```
$fields['code'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
        ->setLabel(t('unique code'))
        ->setDescription(t('Some unique code'))
        ->addConstraint('UniqueField')
        ->setTranslatable(false)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
            'weight' => 4,
        ))
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'weight' => 4,
        ))
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', true)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', true);
```

Creating a new entity in the UI works as expected as long as I do not set the code value to something already in the database. However, as soon as I try to create a new entity with an already existing value for code (thus triggering a constraint violation), I get the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Form\FormState::setError() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php on line 454 in Drupal\Core\Form\FormState->setError() (line 1156 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormState.php).
```

If I change the field definition to use a string instead everything works as expected:

```
$fields['code'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('unique code'))
        ->setDescription(t('Some unique code'))
        ->setSetting('max_length', 5)
        ->addConstraint('UniqueField')
        ->setTranslatable(false)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
            'weight' => 4,
        ))
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'weight' => 4,
        ))
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', true)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', true);
```

So the question is how do I add a unique constraint for an integer field? Is there another validation class I can use, am I setting up my integer field definition wrong thus causing the error, or?

Comment: Maybe see https://www.drupal.org/node/2478663

Comment: I can confirm that the NumberWidget currently throws ``Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Form\FormState::setError() must be of the type array, null given``. I am on Drupal v8.1.7

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an open bug in core. I have filed a bug report containing a makeshift solution on Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2784015/

Edit the file 'core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/NumberWidget.php' to let the errorElement function `return $element[0]['value']` instead of `$element['value']`. So far, I don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a core bug, I believe it should be fairly easy to overcome. The [addConstraint](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!TypedData!DataDefinition.php/function/DataDefinition%3A%3AaddConstraint/8.2.x) method takes a second parameter with options:

```
public DataDefinition::addConstraint($constraint_name, $options = NULL)
```

This defaults to `NULL`, but according to the documentation can also be an array. Your error indicates that an array is expected. So you should be able to use this instead:

```
->addConstraint('UniqueField', [])
```